# How to get HTML element value in Google HTML service App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I'm creating a UI with the GAS HTML service, I'm trying to get the selected element from a drop down list inside an "IF" tag...

```
<select id="MyList">
 <option value="opt1">option 1</option>
 <option value="opt2">option 2</option>
</select>

<? var data = getData(); ?>
 <? for(var i=0; i<10 ;i++)?>
  <? if (data[i] == My List Element?? )?>
 <?}?>
<?}?>
```

So getData() is the function to get the whole data from a Spreadsheet, and the IF inside the  tags will filter the relevant data according to the drop down list selection.
How should be the syntax for this action?

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be a PHP question, and nothing to with GAE.

Comment: Its not php and it's not  appengine. Should be tagged google apps script

Answer (score 0):

This will pass just the value of the listbox once its value changes...

In your .html ...

```
<select id="MyList" onchange = "google.script.run
       .myFunction(this.value)">
 <option value="opt1">option 1</option>
 <option value="opt2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

In your .gs ...

```
function myFunction(value) {
 var data = getData(); 
 for(var i=0; i<10 ;i++)
   if (data[i][0] == value)
     ...
}
```

I threw a [0] in data[i] assuming data[i] is an entire row of spreadsheet data and that you'll want to look at the first column - 0.

Comment: Hi bryanp, thanks for the help!, but I don't find the way to print it through the html file,so my final question is: how I can pass the whole row or rows from "myFunction" to the html output? I'm using the template as it is explained here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: maybe you just need `document.getElementById("MyList").value` to replace your "My List Element"?   `return data[i]` I assume just passes the whole row.